# MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation

Detailes:
VS community, windows 7, "hello world" c program

The error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.  Project1    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  380

Where double click takes me:

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"
    BuildingInIDE                      ="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"
    Sources                            ="@(ClCompile)"
```

Full: https://pastebin.com/8sLUMdFC

Please help me, im lost

Answer (score 1):

`-1073741515` is `0xC0000135`.

Error code `0xC0000135` in turn is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`  Your program misses some DLL.